# How reduce multiple join to same table with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, select, left-join, row, inner-join

How can I reduce multiple joins to a second table with fields ID, DESCRIPTION, and have the results displayed in one row without using UNION or a second select to Table 2?

I've tried doing it this way, but I don't want to be overloaded with queries.
Any way to optimize the select?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 **INNER_1** ON T1.ID_1 = INNER_1.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 **INNER_2** ON T1.ID_2 = INNER_2.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 **INNER_3** ON T1.ID_3 = INNER_3.ID
...
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 1):

The presence of `ID_1, ID_2, ID_3`, etc... columns means your table is not in first normal form (1NF), the first most basic step of data modeling/design. There should be no repeating groups like this. The proper fix is to break out these IDs into their own table:

```
table_1                           table1_table2_xref    table_2
-------                           -----------           -------
{table_1_pk},                     {table_1_pk},         {id}
scalar attributes of table_1...   {id        }          table_2 attrs...
```

Once this is fixed, you then simply do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table1_table2_xref x ON x.table_1_pk = t1.table_1_pk
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON x.id = t2.id
```

That will set you up to perform well regardless of how many IDs you have, vastly simplifies your code, and makes your design resilient and extensible (you can add IDs without changing code).

Comment: I'm sorry, but the tables existed, I'm just making an adjustment. the tables are as follows: Table1: ID - Desc
Table 2: ID - Desc - ID1_Table1 - ID2_Table1 - ID3_Table1

Answer (score 1):

If you are only expecting a single value for each inner `ID` then you can pivot using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.id = T1.id_1 THEN T2.key   END) AS key1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.id = T1.id_1 THEN T2.value END) AS value1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.id = T1.id_2 THEN T2.key   END) AS key2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.id = T1.id_2 THEN T2.value END) AS value2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.id = T1.id_3 THEN T2.key   END) AS key3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.id = T1.id_3 THEN T2.value END) AS value3
FROM   TABLE_1 T1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 T2
         ON T2.ID IN (T1.ID_1, T1.ID_2, T1.ID_3)
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 ( id, id_1, id_2, id_3 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4, 5, 6 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_2 (id, key, value) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'key' || level, CHR(64+LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;
```

Outputs:

| ID | KEY1 | VALUE1 | KEY2 | VALUE2 | KEY3 | VALUE3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | key1 | A | key2 | B | key3 | C |
| 2 | key4 | D | key5 | E | key6 | F |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qlSwA5Zg)